# ImageMagick.MagickResourceLimitErrorException: 'TooManyExceptions (exception processing is suspended)

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I am getting this error:

```
ImageMagick.MagickResourceLimitErrorException: 'TooManyExceptions (exception processing is suspended) @ error/exception.c/ThrowException/969'
```

On this line

```
using (MagickImageCollection tiffPageCollection = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    tiffPageCollection.Read(tifName);  // fails here.
}
```

The problem occurs because the 92 page tif has three errors like this on each page:

```
{"ASCII value for tag \"Copyright\" does not end in null byte. `TIFFFetchNormalTag' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1007"}    ImageMagick.MagickException {ImageMagick.MagickCoderWarningException}
```

The number of warning errors is exceeded so that triggers TooManyExceptions errors.

This URL alludes to a solution:

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=33989

of adding this handler:

```
private void MagickNET_Log (object sender, LogEventArgs e)
{
    // write to a single log file...
    if ((RemoteImageMagickEventLogging & e.EventType) != LogEvents.None)
    {
        switch (e.EventType)
        {
        case LogEvents.Exception:
            if (!e.Message.Contains ("TIFFWarnings"))
            {
                 TriggerRemoteLoggingEvent (e.EventType, 
                     EZLogger.LoggingLevel.Note1, e.Message);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It also references that this exception was added to "ImageMagick.Net 7.4.5 Q8 AnyCPU" and did not happen on earlier versions.  I am experiencing the problem on "ImageMagick.Net-Q16-AnyCPU v7.9.1"  I updated to v7.10.0 and still had the same problem.

So, my questions are:

1. What versions of ImageMagick have and don't have this feature?
2. What are the steps to handing that handler to my code?
3. Is there a way to increase the maximum number of allowed warnings and I can just raise that limit to something so high that I will not hit it?

Comment: There is no such version as 7.4.8 in ImageMagick. The current version is 7.0.8.23. Perhaps that is a version of Magick.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Magick.NET 7.10.1.0: https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/releases/tag/7.10.1.0. The `TooManyExceptions (exception processing is suspended)` exception will no longer be thrown because this has been changed into a warning.

Answer (score 0):

> What versions of ImageMagick have and don't have this feature?

From the [changelog](https://imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php), it was added as early as version 7.0.7-22. The body of work around this feature was in response to [Google's OSS-fuzz project](https://opensource.google.com/projects/oss-fuzz).

> Is there a way to increase the maximum number of allowed warnings and I can just raise that limit to something so high that I will not hit it?

Not currently. The limit is hardcoded `MagickCore/exception.c` as ...

```c
#define MaxExceptionList 64
```

But this is opensource, and a rather new feature. If you post an issue under 'Bugs' [message board](https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/), you may be able to have the developers revise the limit, or allow some resource attribute under [polices.xml](https://imagemagick.org/source/policy.xml) to be controlled by the user. Presenting a real world test-case also helps, and tiff file with 64+ warnings should require some level of scrutiny.

Comment: it is a multipage tiff and the same three warning errors occur on each page.  The warnings are harmless as far as I am concerned.  The link I provided above has a link to a sample.  My sample contains private data.